# Can I use a single wildcard cert across many AWS elastic load balancers (ELB)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

Can I use a single wildcard cert across many AWS elastic load balancers (ELB)?

Each ELB is in a different AWS account.  Or do I need a different cert for each ELB?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from using a single wildcard cert in multiple ELBs, across multiple AWS accounts, and even across other types of servers outside AWS entirely. There is no technical limitation that would prevent this from working.

Note that AWS now [provides SSL certificates for free](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/), for use with ELBs and/or CloudFront.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Mark.  I wish certificate manager was supported in Ireland.  But we can make do.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don’t need to purchase an individual certificate for each ELB. You will get multiple server licenses with wildcard certificate that you can apply the same certificate in different ELBs over different AWS accounts.